# Color schemes for text ads

Tags: color, color-scheme, advertisement, marketing

What are the most effective color schemes for text ads? Google's default is blue for headlines, black for body texts and green for links.

[The Norwegian Color Empire](http://www.fargerike.no/) gave the "Color of the year" award for 2013 to purple - based on [a study](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=no&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&eotf=1&u=http://www.bt.no/bolig/Dette-er-arets-farge-2828641.html) by [Norstat](http://norstat.no) - which concluded that black, grey, beige, brown and pink make people sad, whereas red, blue, yellow, green and purple make people happy.

- Has anyone applied similar colors to text ads with great success?
- Should my text ads be made up of multiple or single colors?

Comment: What kind of ads are you talking about, are you using images or only type? this question is almost impossible to answer without knowing what are you trying to achieve. Also depending who are you targeting. For example orange was used most in blockbuster trailers http://boxofficequant.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Hue-Density.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this nice read

http://library.thinkquest.org/08aug/01276/colorsanddesign/colorinadvertising.html

Color scheme for your text ads should ideally depend on the color scheme of your web page. Choose slightly different color from your existent text color in your web page to make it distinguishable enough as an ad but still blended enough to not to look an entirely different section in your website.

Comment: Interesting read but I think I might be mildly blinded now due to the color choices of that website. I recommend select text-copy-paste into notepad-read article. Picking colors that are complimentary to a page's color scheme may make your ads pop, but you would also not want to be too annoying/distracting from the primary content